# Can there be a Nietzschean Will to Power when our subonscious affects our desires which are dictated by ideology as Zizek points out?

Tags: nietzsche, free-will, zizek

Does nietzsche argue there is free will ? how can he simultaneously claim our desire is affected by the subconscious and also claim that we must figure those out and assert our will when Zizek explains that subconscious is dictated by ideology ?

Comment: Don't take Zizek too seriously :)

Comment: From a Wikipedia article w/ citations: ['Freidrich Nietzche and free will'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche_and_free_will#:~:text=The%2019th%2Dcentury%20philosopher%20Friedrich,his%20opinion%2C%20does%20not%20exist.): _"The 19th-century philosopher Friedrich Nietzsche is known as a critic of Judeo-Christian morality and religions in general. One of the arguments he raised against the truthfulness of these doctrines is that they are based upon the concept of free will, which, in his opinion, does not exist"._